# Cloud ML: Jobs vs Operations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

While reading Cloud ML documentation I constantly stuck to the 'operation' term. Can please somebody explain to what it refers to and how it's connected with Cloud ML Jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways jobs and operations differ:

1. Jobs are for training or prediction. Operations are for create/update/deleting models an dversions.
2. Jobs are both the input and output of an API call. Operations are output only.
3. With jobs, you specify the job ID (so you can re-submit on 5xx error without duplicating the job). With operations, the operation ID is assigned automatically.
4. The Operation object is the same across numerous GCP services, but the Job object is unique to ML Engine.

Honestly this doesn't make a huge amount of sense for API design. I'm guessing what happend is Operation got used in the [standard GCP way](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#long_running_operations) for simple functions, however for training/prediction this was insufficient so the API designer added the Job object.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs tend to be long lived things like treating a model or doing batch prediction.

Operations tend to be things like create-read-update-delete operations on deployed models.